Moving "Home" link to left of Nav BaR
I have a nav set as my header and want to have a Link to the home page. My Div is set as justify-content-center to center the text of the form, however I can't seem to place the .homeLink to the left. Any suggestions?
 <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-warning justify-content-center">
           <span class="homeLink">Home</span> 
            <div class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 fw-bolder fs-1">Incident Report</div>
        </div>
    </nav>

I tried using flex in CSS to align-items or use flex but no such luck.

Please provide full code with image of error

there is css property margin:auto that will help here, i have tested it in local compiler. reference image
 .homeLink{
margin-right: auto; }

